# How to make python decorators work like a tag to make function calls "by tag"

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm a python beginner and have an idea of the basic concept of decorators. I have worked on Python-Behave before and the framework allows you to insert a decorator and it would function like a tag. I'm trying to replicate this in a framework I'm currently building.

**custom arg in the CLI**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--type', help='foo help')
args = parser.parse_args() #args.type would receive the value
```

**CLI**

```
python run.py --type=A
```

**Functions**

```
   @typeA
   def foo_func():
      print "type A ran"

   @typeB
   def bar_func():
      print "type B ran"
```

**Expected output**

```
"type A ran"
```

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what the problem is, so you might want to add some information. It might also be a good idea to read the [documentation on function definition](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function).

Comment: If you did it that way, you'd need a separate decorator function for each possible value of the argument.  Something like ``@type('A')``, ``@type('B')`` would probably be a better approach - although preferably with a different name than that, as 'type' is a built-in object name.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your decorator up into a class style decorator to avoid having hanging variables and use a memoized factory function to create the tags.

```
import functools

class TagDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, tagName):
        self.functions = []
        self.tagName = tagName

    def __str__(self):
        return "<TagDecorator {tagName}>".format(tagName=self.tagName)

    def __call__(self, f):
        self.functions.append(f)
        return f

    def invoke(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [f(*args, **kwargs) for f in self.functions]


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)  # memoization
def get_func_tag(tagName):
    return TagDecorator(tagName)
```

Now we create our tags:

```
tagA = get_func_tag("A")
tagB = get_func_tag("B")

@tagA
def funcA_1(*args, **kwargs):
    print("A", args, kwargs)

# another way
@get_func_tag("A")
def funcA_2(*args, **kwargs):
    print("A too", args, kwargs)

@tagB
def funcB_1():
    print("B")

@tagB
def funcB_2():
    print("B too")

# invoke all functions registered with tagA : passing arguments
tagA.invoke("hello", who="dolly")

# invoke all functions registered with tagA, another way.
get_func_tag("A").invoke()

# actually get_func_tag always returns the same instance
# for a given tagName, thanks to lru_cache
assert get_func_tag("A") == tagA

# Of course tagB can be invoked
tagB.invoke()
get_func_tag("B").invoke()

# but passing it args would be an error.
tagB.invoke("B")  # TypeError: funcB_1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Care has to be taken about the tagged functions' arguments. If for one same tag, you register signatures which vary, you will certainly have issues when invoking them. You can take care of this using the [inspect.signature](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/inspect.html) function. But real signature matching is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Use decorator to store a reference to a function in dictionary. Use user input to retrieve function from dictionary. Call it afterwards.

```
REGISTER = {}

def register(name):
    def wrapper(f):
        print f, 'registered'
        REGISTER[name] = f
        return f
    return wrapper

@register('A')
def foo():
    print 'foo called'

@register('B')
def bar():
    print 'bar called'

name = 'A'  # or args.type
func_to_call = REGISTER[name]
func_to_call()  # actual call is done here
```